# Using repeater, take FK and display column from that table

Tags: asp.net, linq

Using a repeater I run through the 'SelectedUtility' table and output where a match is made.
This works fine as it is, however it displays the 'Utility_Id' which is a foreign key to to 'id' in the Utility Table.

I actually want to display the 'name' column inside the Utility table. How Can i do this...
something like `<th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Utility_Id.name") %></th>`
or is it done in code behind...thanks for any response

aspx:

```
 <asp:Repeater id="rptSelectedUtilities" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
                        <tr>   
                            <th style="width:200px;">Utility</th>    
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Utility_Id") %></th> 
                        </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind:

```
DBData db = new DBDatat();
        List<Select_Utility> SelectedUtility = 
            (from SU in db.Select_Utilities
             where SU.Work_Id == 3
             select SU).ToList();

        rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = SelectedUtility;
```

rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();

---

EDIT:

```
   DBData db = new DBDatat();
    List<Utility_Company> Utility = new List<Utility_Company>();
    List<Select_Utility> SelectedUtility = 
        (from SU in db.Select_Utilities
         join UTL in Utility on SU equals UTL.id
         where SU.Worksite_Id == 3
         select SU).ToList();

    rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = SelectedUtility;
    rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();
```

Throws the error 'the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'join'

//shouldt the join be to the name..so  join UTL in Utility on SU equals UTL.Name //instead of UTL.id

Also tried join UTL in db.Utility_Companies on SU equals UTL.id...buit same error

---

**SECOND EDIT:
 <%# Eval("Name") %>
throws error:DataBinding: 'Select_Utility' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.**

```
     DBData db = new DBData();

        List<Select_Utility> SelectedUtility = 
            (from SU in db.Select_Utilities
             where SU.Worksite_Id == 3
             select SU).ToList();

        rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = SelectedUtility;
        rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();


   List<Utility_Company> Utility = new List<Utility_Company>();
        var query = from u in db.Utility_Companies
                    join su in db.Select_Utilities
                         on u.id equals su.Utility_Id
                    where su.Worksite_Id == 3
                    select u;

        rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = query.ToList();
        rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query (you should select joined utilities):

```
DBData db = new DBDatat();
var query = from u in db.Utility
            join su in db.Select_Utilities
                 on u.Id equals su.Utility_Id
            where su.Work_Id == 3
            select u;

rptSelectedUtilities.DataSource = query.ToList();
rptSelectedUtilities.DataBind();
```

Page (display name of utility):

```
<th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
```

Comment: DataBinding: 'Select_Utility' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'. is the error im getting. 'name' isnt contained inside the 'Select_utility' its found inside 'Utility' Table, The 'Select utility' does hold the 'Utility Id' though?????

Comment: do i delete the first Linq then? still getting error with DataBinding: 'Select_Utility' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'....please see my second edit for my code...thank you

Comment: @John you should not get that error, because in my answer list of `Utility` objects is assigned to repeater. There is no `Select_Utility`. Yes, remove completely your query.

Answer (score 1):

Use Inner join the foreign table. and select that id .

```
DBData db = new DBDatat();
        List<Select_Utility> SelectedUtility = 
            (from SU in db.Select_Utilities join UTL in Utility on SU equals UTL.Utility_Id
             where SU.Work_Id == 3
             select SU).ToList();
```